# Setting MySQL as the metastore for built in spark hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have an spark, scala sbt project using spark. I need to multiple create HiveContexts, which is not allowed by the built in derby for spark hive. Can someone help me with setting up mysql as the metastore instead of derby, which is the default db. I don't have actual hive installed or spark installed. I use sbt dependency for spark and hive.

Answer (score 0):

Copy hive-site.xml file in Spark's conf directory and change some properties in that file

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
  <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hive</value>
  <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
```

Comment: my project is an sbt project, which uses spark jar. There is no conf directory anywhere.  Tried creating a conf directory in the project root directory, but without any effect.

Comment: Not in your project, Go to Cluster's configuration directory where other conf files are reside like spark-default.conf and spark-env.sh. Then copy hive-site.xml file in this dir and change the properties

Comment: i'm not using a cluster, but a spark jar. There are no other configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Shakti

You need to have the conf files in the class path. I'm using hadoop, hive, and spark with Intellij. In Intellij I have file:/usr/local/spark/conf/, file:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/, and file:/usr/local/hive/conf/ in my class path. You can use following to print your run time class path:

```
  val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
  cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)
```

I hope this help if you haven't already found a fix.